# Difference between thermodynamical, statistical, and dynamical equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, equilibrium, galaxies, boltzmann-equation

I have two related questions concerning the difference between thermodynamic, statistical mechanical, and dynamical equilibrium. In particular, I am thinking about the statistical physics of galaxies, and the example I have in mind is those systems that can be modelled via the collisionless Boltzmann equation in equilibrium (the equation [here](https://galaxiesbook.org/chapters/I-04.-Equilibria-Spherical-Collisionless-Systems.html#The-collisionless-Boltzmann-equation) called *equilibrium collisionless Boltzmann equation* 6.36):

> For a system in equilibrium, the number of stars in a given region of phase-space does not change, so ∂f(x,v,t)/∂t=0. For such systems, the collisionless Boltzmann equation reduces to: $\dot q \frac{∂f(q,p)}{∂q} + \dot p \frac{∂f(q,p)}{∂p}=0$. This is the equilibrium collisionless Boltzmann equation.

My questions are:

1. Is that equilibrium defined by the time-independence of the distribution function $f$ a kind of dynamical equilibrium or a statistical mechanical equilibrium (i.e. we have statistical mechanical equilibrium when the probability density has no explicit time dependence)?
2. If that's a statistical mechanical equilibrium, does that also imply thermodynamical equilibrium? That is, is thermodynamical equilibrium implied by the application of the equilibrium collision-less Boltzmann equation?